# Format output right to left

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to learn how to format print to make it look neat. My program would count how many vowels are in a piece of text. But wont print the way I would like which is right to left

As example - 
             I would like it to print as:

```
a : 100
e :  50
i :  31
o :  10
u :   1
```

Currently I have it printing as the following:

```
a : 100
e : 50
i : 31
o : 10
u : 1
```

Here is my code and the printing option so far....

```
import sys


vowels = {i:0 for i in 'aeiou'}

def check(string):
    for char in string:
        if char in vowels:
           vowels[char] +=1
    return vowels

def main():
    for line in sys.stdin:
        lines = line.lower().strip()

        check(lines)

    sortvowels = sorted(vowels, key=vowels.get, reverse=True)
    for r in sortvowels:
        print(' {:} {} {:>d}'.format(r,":",vowels[r]))

    #for keys, values in sorted(vowels.items(),reverse=False):
    #   print('{} : {:d}'.format(keys, vowels[maximum]))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Why do you post all this code, if basically just one line is your problem? Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). And I don't see that you actually define `d` anywhere.

Comment: I posted all my code so people could see what I was doing.

Comment: The alignment operation `{:>d}` needs a width. Try something like `{:5>d}` instead

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by obtaining the max value from my dictionary,

I had to add the additional code,

```
formt = max(vowels.values())
finalformat = len(str(formt))
```

I did this by `formt = max(vowels.values())`

In order to actually use this, I had to convert that into a string.

I did this by `finalformat = len(str(formt))`

To finally be able to print I did the following:

```
sortvowels = sorted(vowels, key=vowels.get, reverse=True)
for r in sortvowels:
    print('{} {} {:>{}}'.format(r,":",vowels[r],finalformat))
```